# Remove links on WordPress pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know it is beginner questions but I can't find it anywhere. How to remove the links that are shown on all of my WordPress pages under title for example: Home » Contact Us ? I guess it is possible to hide it with CSS.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, frankly, too many. You need to include more detail, screenshots, code or links to live examples

Answer (score 0):

As Serg says there are many ways to do this. With CSS you can set:

`.the-link { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is breadcrumbs, you may have the option in all the pages, check with the hide/display breadcrumbs option in the pages.

Or if you use the plugin for breadcrumbs , or inspect the class and put `display:none` for the particular class in custom css

Please provide your working url if you not solved this yet.

Comment: Thanks ! this is what I needed